# Mixpanel - Does not seem accurate, events I expect are not seen

Tags: analytics, mixpanel

So I created an Insights Board as seen below:
[image]

So basically all events but unique users and only users that I give a distinct ID too (i.e. logged in users).

Now after viewing the board I went to my website and logged in with a users that is not part of those 4. I could then see events being fired to mixpanel.

However I still only see 4 events even though I should see a 5th.

Any ideas?

In general it seems mixpanel is quite inaccurate or is it me?